# Como implementar metodo de busqueda con Ajax y JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, ajax, asp.net

E tratado de implementar un simple metodo de busqueda con ajax y Jquery, para buscar por entidades "FitnessGoal" las cuales son creadas por el usuario.
Trate de implementarlo por mi mismo pero al buscar no regresa nada, son correctos mi metodo y codigo ajax?

Esta es la view index:

```
    @model IEnumerable<FitnessWebApplication.Models.FitnessGoals>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<h2>Your Fitness Goals</h2>

<div>
    <b>Search By:</b>
    <select id="SearchBy">
        <option value="Name">Name</option>
        <option value="ID">ID</option>
    </select><br /><br />

    @Html.TextBox("Search")<input type="submit" id="SearchBtn" value="Search" /><br /><br />

</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Goal)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StartDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FinishDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Weight) (kg)
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Weight) (kg)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <tbody id="DataSearching">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Goal)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FinishDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Weight) kg
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>



</table>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#SearchBtn").click(function () {
            var SearchBy = $("#SearchBy").val();
            var SearchValue = $("#Search").val();
            var SetData = $("#DataSearching").val();
            SetData.html("");

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "/Home/GetSearchingData?SearchBy=" + SearchBy + "&SearchValue=" + SearchValue,
                contentType: "html",
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.length == 0) {
                        setData.append('<tr style="color:red"><td colspan="3">No match Data</td></tr>')
                    }
                    else {
                        $.each(result, function (index, value) {
                            var Data = "<tr>" +
                                "<td>"
                                + value.Name +
                                "</td>"
                            "<td>"
                                + value.Goal +
                                "</td>"
                            "<td>"
                                + value.StartDate +
                                "</td>"
                            "<td>"
                                + value.FinishDate +
                                "</td>"
                            "<td>"
                                + value.Weight +
                                "</td>"
                            "</tr>"
                            SetData.append(Data);

                        })
                    }

                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

El metodo para buscar del controller FitnessGoalsController:

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        public JsonResult GetSearchingData(string SearchBy, string SearchValue)
        {
            List<FitnessGoals> FitnessGoals = new List<FitnessGoals>();
            if(SearchBy == "ID")
            {
                try
                {
                    int Id = Convert.ToInt32(SearchValue);
                    FitnessGoals = db.FitnessGoals.Where(x => x.ID == Id || SearchValue == null).ToList();

                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} is Not a ID", SearchValue);

                }   
                return Json(FitnessGoals, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                FitnessGoals = db.FitnessGoals.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(SearchValue) || SearchValue == null).ToList();
                return Json(FitnessGoals, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }
        }
```

al usar el boton "Search" me salta la siguiente exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: SetData.html is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (FitnessGoals:175)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (VM432 jquery-1.12.4.js:5226)
    at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle (VM432 jquery-1.12.4.js:4878)
```

Comment: F12 y mira hacia dónde está apuntando las llamadas...

Comment: En principio en el success del ajax tendrías que poner `$("#DataSearching").html(Data)` o `$("#DataSearching").append(Data)` no `SetData.append(Data);`

Comment: Ahora arregle el problema del URL, pero me salta error en la linea :SetData.html("");

Comment: Pero quitando las lineas anteriores, lo unico que hara es seguir añadiendo el resultado de regreso en la table.

Comment: Listo funciona ahora, reemplaze //SetData.html(""); por

            $("#DataSearching").html("");

Comment: puedes agregar como lo resolviste como respuesta

Comment: Pero sigue aviendo un problema, solo me regresa el nombre y no los demas atributos

Comment: dentro de `$.each(result, function (index, value) {` agrega esta línea: `console.log("value: ",value);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los errores mas importantes fueron:

1. El **URL** en el **Ajax** puntaba a otra direccion, el URL correcto era: **"/FitnessGoals/GetSearchingData?SearchBy="**
2. En el **Ajax**, la **variable data =** .... , faltaban algunos signos +
3. En vez de **SetData.html("");** use un :**$("#DataSearching").html("");**

Solucionando estos errores, el programa funcionaba.

Este es el codigo actualizado de la view:

```
    @model IEnumerable<FitnessWebApplication.Models.FitnessGoals>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<h2>Your Fitness Goals</h2>

<div>
    <b>Search By:</b>
    <select id="SearchBy">
        <option value="Name">Name</option>
    </select><br /><br />

    @Html.TextBox("Search")<input type="submit" id="SearchBtn" value="Search" /><br /><br />

</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Goal)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StartDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FinishDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Weight) (kg)
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <tbody id="DataSearching">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Goal)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FinishDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Weight) kg
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>



</table>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#SearchBtn").click(function () {
            var SearchBy = $("#SearchBy").val();
            var SearchValue = $("#Search").val();
            //var SetData = $("#DataSearching").val();
            //SetData.html("");

            $("#DataSearching").html("");

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "/FitnessGoals/GetSearchingData?SearchBy=" + SearchBy + "&SearchValue=" + SearchValue,
                contentType: "html",
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.length == 0) {
                        //setData.append('<tr style="color:red"><td colspan="3">No match Data</td></tr>')
                        $("#DataSearching").html('<tr style="color:red"><td colspan="3">No match Data</td></tr>')
                    }
                    else {
                        $.each(result, function (index, value) {
                            console.log("value: ", value);

                            var Data = "<tr>" +
                                "<td>"
                                + value.Name +
                                "</td>" +
                                "<td>"
                                + value.Goal +
                                "</td>" +
                                "<td>"
                                + value.StartDate +
                                "</td>" +
                                "<td>"
                                + value.FinishDate +
                                "</td>" +
                                "<td>"
                                + value.Weight +
                                "</td>" +
                                "</tr>"
                            $("#DataSearching").append(Data)

                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```